# How to create Encrypted Home Directories with Synology NAS

Tags: synology, dsm

I have the need to encrypt folders in users home directories, it doesn't appear to be supported out of the box for some unknown reason. So how do I go about creating encrypted home directories with Synology NAS?

Answer (score 1):

They support this now.

Control Panel > Shared Folders > home

In the menu click, Edit > Encryption

Comment: When attempting this, I get a warning saying all user home folders will be moved to another unencrypted volume. This is DSM 7.1 on RS1221+. I'm not finding much information about this at all, searching led me here.